# Delete specific of word using sed in unix

Tags: string, bash, sed, substring

I have a string variable `Short_name="This_is_test_string"`

I want to output the substring `test_string` from the `Short_name` variable using `sed`.

Comment: Are you saying you have a variable named `Short_name` whose value is `"This_is_test_string"` or a variable whose value is `Short_name="This_is_test_string"` or something else? Why do you need to use sed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need sed. [Bash parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) will do:

```
$ Short_name="This_is_test_string"
$ echo "${Short_name##*_is_}"
test_string
```

That removes everything from the beginning of the string up to and including the *last* "_is_"

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
echo 'Short_name="This_is_test_string"' | sed 's/.*_is_//;s/"//'
```

Breaking it down:

```
s           -- substitute command
/           -- delimiter
.*_is_      -- match this
                 .*     -- any character (.), as many as possible (*)
                 _is_   -- these 4 exact characters
/           -- delimiter
(nothing)   -- what to replace any match with
/           -- delimiter
;           -- end this command, start another
s           -- substitute command
/           -- delimiter
"           -- match this character
/           -- delimiter
(nothing)   -- what to replace any match with
/           -- delimiter
```

**[EDIT]**

The key is figuring out which pattern matches your needs (which I don't yet have a good understanding of).  Perhaps this:

```
... | sed 's/.*[[:<:]]is[ _]*//;s/"//'
```

The "tricky bit" here is `[[:<:]]` which is a "zero width assertion" (in this case "beginning of word") which keeps us from doing the wrong thing on inputs like this:

```
echo 'string2=is  this it"' | sed 's/.*[[:<:]]is[ _]*//;s/"//'
```

*(by keeping us from matching the "is" in "this")*

Comment: I just tried using below way, 
string="this_is_my_test_name" 
final=$(echo ${string} | sed 's/^.*is_//;') which gives expected output. but, if scenario is like, 
string2=is 
then below code is not working, 
final=$(echo ${string} | sed 's/^.*${string2}_//;') 
how to use variable string2?

Comment: got solution,

final=$(echo ${string} | sed 's/^.*'$o_string'_//;')